# how to filter in PHP array when filters are flexible to set

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have a PHP array that I show on my website using `foreach`. I check with an if statement if the status of the item is "online":

```
if($value['status'] == "online"){ ...etc
```

Now I want to be able to let users add filtering on the results, for example the type:

```
if($value['status'] == "online" && $value['type'] == $type ){ ...etc
```

There are many filter options, and people can set as many as they want (or none). How can I implement this the best?

Is there a way I can leave `$type` open, so type is not filtered?

```
if($value['status'] == "online" && $value['type'] == "SOMETHING SO IT DOESN'T FILTER" ){ ...etc
```

Or is there a way I can add all the filters depending on if they are set?

```
if($value['status'] == "online" && if(isset($type)){$value['type'] == $type} ){ ...etc
```

I guess there must be an easy way but I can't find it.

EDIT:
I solved my problem by using array_filter for each filter. If the filter is set, then I update my array. For example the "type" filter:

```
if($type !== ""){
    $myArray= array_filter($myArray, function ($var) use ($type) {
        return ($var['type'] == $type);
    });
}
```

Comment: One line of code is not enough to know what is going on.

Comment: My question is only about that first line though, that's why I didn't put more. I fixed my problem btw, by running every filter option through array_filter. I hoped for something shorter, but there seems to be no way.

Comment: Can you please post your solution in your Question @Irene?

Comment: ***I hoped for something shorter, but there seems to be no way.*** If you say so then it must be true. I mean it would make no sense that anyone else knows anything better.

Comment: I did not mean it like that, I posted my question to see if someone knew how to do it. Besides this I googled for hours, but with no result.

Comment: And that is why I said, one line of code is not enough to give us clues on how to solve it. do you see the catch 22 here....

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear then. I could add some random code of what I could possibly do after the if statement, but that really doesn't affect the situation. All I would like to know is how to make an if statement flexible.